# Use a paremeter variable in method call (JAVA)

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

I have a class named Employee. I'm trying to use a for loop with a parameter variable to display information for each employee (there are 3) instead of having to separately write out the display for each employee.

I'd like to use the 'setName' variable to the 'employee1' part of the method call. Is this possible?

```
            // Create the first employee using non-argument constructor
            Employee employee1 = new Employee();

            employee1.setName("Susan Meyers");          // Set the name
            employee1.setDepartment("Accounting");      // Set department
            employee1.setPosition("Vice President");    // Set position
            employee1.setID(47899);                     // Set ID Number


            // Create the second employee using all argument constructor
            Employee employee2 = new Employee("Mark Jones", "IT", "Programmer", 39119);


            // Create employee three using two-argument constructor
            Employee employee3 = new Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774);

            employee3.setDepartment("Manufacturing");   // Set department
            employee3.setPosition("Engineer");          // Set position


            // Display the data for employees 1, 2, 3 using for loop
            for(int e = 1; e <= 3; e++) {

                Integer.toString(e);
                String setName = "employee" + "e";


                System.out.println("Name: " + employee1.getName());
            }
```

Comment: You need to use a array.

Answer (score 0):

just create a list of employees a put employee1 employee2 and employee in it and later loop over the list.

```
 List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(employee1);
employees.add(employee2);
employees.add(employee3);
```

Your loop

```
for(Employee employee: employees){
System.out.println(employee);
}
```

You can also add a toString Method to your employee class to make the work easy for yourself

```
public class Employee
....
....

getter/setter

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee ID: " + id + "\nName: " + name + "\nDept: " + department + "\nPosition: " + position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `toString()` inside of your `Employee` class and place all relevant information you want printed from that.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee ID: " + id + "\nName: " + name + "\nDept: " + department + "\nPosition: " + position;
}
```

You can then just print it in a normal `System.out.println` call.

```
System.out.println(employee1);
```

Comment: Put the @Override at the bottom of the class?

And use the println statement in the main? Would I have to use 3 println statements for each employee in main?

Comment: You put `@Override` before the signature of the method you're overriding.  Remember - `Object` has its own `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?:
This will create 3 employees, Employee 1, 2 and 3.

```
          for(int e = 1; e <= 3; e++) {                  
               Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
                newemployee.SetName("employee" + e);    
                System.out.println("Name: " + newEmployee.getName());
            }
```

ofcourse, they will be out of memory once you try to acces them so you can store them in a list:

```
 List<Employee> ListOfEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

  for(int e = 1; e <= 3; e++) {                  
      Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
      newemployee.SetName("employee" + e);    
      ListOfEmployees.Add(newEmployee); 
       System.out.println("Name: " + newEmployee.getName());
     }
```

afterwards, you can access a specific employee like this:

```
ListOfEmployees[1].SetName("some name"); //this is the first employee that was added to the list in the for-loop above here
ListOfEmployees[1].GetName(); // returns "some name"
```